# 2d icon arrays JAVA and printing out in JOptionpane box

Tags: java

How would I create a 2d icon array and print it out in a JOptionPane box. so Far I have this, but when I print it out it shows a bunch of BlockEmpty.png

```
public class iconarray{

public static void main (String [] args)


{
    Icon blockempty = new ImageIcon("BlockEmpty.png");

    Icon Board [] [] = new Icon [8] [8];
    String GameBoard = "";
    for (int count2 = 2; count2 <= 7; count2++)
    {

        for (int count3 = 1; count3 <= 7; count3++)
        {
            Board[count2][count3] = blockempty;
         }
    }
    for (int count2 = 2; count2 <= 7; count2++)
     {
        for (int count3 = 1; count3 <= 7; count3++)
        {
            GameBoard = GameBoard + Board[count2][count3];
        }
        GameBoard = GameBoard + "\n"; 
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Connect 4", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, blockempty);
}
```

}

Comment: you never modify in loops `blockEmpty`

Comment: An icon needs something to be displayed on, such as `JLabel`, which, inturn needs to be added to a displayable component, like a `JPanel`, which can then be passed to the dialog as the `msg` parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display a `Icon` or `Image`, you first need some way to render it.  `Icon`s and `Image`s don't have the means to render them selves (*per se*), but require another component that can render them.

Something else a lot of people forget, is `JOptionPane` is capable of display components.

For example:

[image]

```
Icon brick = new ImageIcon(BoardOption.class.getResource("/images.jpg"));
JPanel wall = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));
JLabel bricks[][] = new JLabel[8][8];

for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        bricks[y][x] = new JLabel(brick);
        wall.add(bricks[y][x]);
    }
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wall, "Another brick in the wall", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
```

Take a look at [How to use icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more details.

Comment: That makes a nice change ;)

Comment: Where did the GridLayout come from

Comment: Sorry but I am very new to programing

Comment: Check out [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)